# How to convert PointerByReference image to Byte[] then BITMAP using JAVA/JNA?

Tags: java, c++, pointers, jna, dib

i'm using JNA to work with a scanner's library "LSAPI.DLL" so, after the scan i get a frontimg parameter which is a Pointer of a Dib format, so i have to convert it to a Byte[] then convert the Byte[] to a bitmap and finally save the scanned image on my desktop to test.

this is the method that gave me the Pointer of the frontimg :

```
int a1 = lsApi.LSReadImage(hConnect.getValue(), fgWindow, LsApiConst.CLEAR_ALL_BLACK, (char) LsApiConst.SIDE_FRONT_IMAGE, LsApiConst.READMODE_BRUTTO, NrDoc, frontimg, backimg, R1, R2);
```

i tried to start with this but it doesn't work :

```
Pointer p = frontimg.getValue();
byte[] buffer = p.getByteArray(0, frontimg.getValue().SIZE);
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
    ImageIO.write(img,"BMP", new File("D:/image.BMP")); 
    System.out.println("image created");
```

is there any way to proceed ?

Comment: Can you find documentation on how to convert DIB to Bitmap using w32 APIs?  JNA really has very little to do with it until you know the basic APIs to use.

Comment: it works in .Net by converting DIB to Byte[] then to Bitmap using this class 'BITMAPINFOHEADER' that i found too in JNA Library.          - IntPtr ptr = GlobalLock(frontimg);
    - byte[] buffer = HGlobalToByteArray(ptr);
    - GlobalUnlock(frontimg);